# antMatchers overrides each other if they have the same prefixes

Tags: spring-boot, security

In spring boot I have endpoints protected by extending **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** class. So I can protect the entire controller by adding

```
ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry request = http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests();

request.antMatchers("controller-path/**").hasAnyRole("READ_WRITE", "READ");
request.and().httpBasic();
```

So whoever has the role **READ_WRITE** or **READ** can access the entire controller.

Now problem occurs when I add something like this(code snippet below) and try to authenticate by user that only has **WRITE** role and try to call endpoint **controller-path/update-something**. Somehow spring boot sees that that are role assigned on the endpoint that starts on **controller-path**(assigned roles on that prefix are "READ_WRITE", "READ") and it doesn't allow me to access that endpoint as the user has only "WRITE" role.

```
request.antMatchers("controller-path/**").hasAnyRole("READ_WRITE", "READ");
request.antMatchers("controller-path/update-something").hasAnyRole("WRITE");
```

In other words first antMatcher overrides second antMatcher.

I observed this behavior by implementing ApplicationListener and listen AuthorizationFailureEvent.

I hope I explained it well. Any ideas about what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, your first antmatcher uses `/**` which means, that anything up from here und under everything will be treated by the assigned role. No need to read further, since you've specified this path already. `controller-path/**` includes `controller-path/update-something` as well.

Comment: To put it another way: first match wins

Comment: Hi @Slevin, 
So is there a way to give two similar endpoints to different roles?

Comment: Yes, just put the more precicely one first - as said, first match wins. In your case, what you've set up doesn't make sense, since you declare everything to be read- and writeable. Even when you swap the routes, it wouldn't make any difference. - edit, wll no: if wou swap, you could only write but not read the update-something path

Comment: And you can always fine-tune at conroller-level with method security - a real powerful way to restrict at any depth you need.

Comment: Since I can't edit my previous comment (SO is sometimes really f****ing hard to understand), for clarification: if you swap your routes, say you put the `/update-something` first, every hit which meets this route, will be treated by the applied criteria, in your way then `WRITE` only, but no read allowed. Don't know why you'd do this that way, but the route was caught first and thus handled via the applied restricitons.

Comment: Yes, I tried to swap it, but I got another issue. Now the user with roles "READ_WRITE" and "READ" don't have access to the endpoint "controller-path/update-something" :( It's a matter of how I manage and organize roles. In my case, I should apply the "WRITE" role to the first user because it has access to the root-level path.

Comment: Yes, it's all about a well structured organized role management. If the basic functions are not sufficient, there are always ways to put extra levels of fine-grain into the mix. You should read Spring Security's documentation to get an overview, and if then there are still open wishes, there are also further ways to manage this. But as far as I can see, your problems can be resolved by just putting some thoughts into your securtiy design.